# Update a table if it matches a string

Tags: javascript

I wanted to update my table if the string matches a 
a table cell

example if my string  value is jhonyy
I want to update a row where it contains jhonyy as a value and update its 3rd column which is age via textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var table = document.getElementById("tbl_test");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       //iterate through rows
       //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
         //iterate through columns
         //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
       }  
     }
    </script>`
```

I did some research and only got stuck here.I don't know how to access the rows and cells.

[image]

here is the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table id="tbl_test" style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jhonyy</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <br />
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button id="btn_test" value="test" onclick="test_table()">Test</button>
  <input type="text" id="txt_test" name="txt_test">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test_table()
    {
     var table = document.getElementById("tbl_test");
     for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
     if (cell.textContent == 'jhonyy') 
     {
      change_text();
    }
  }  
}
}
function change_text() {
  var x = document.getElementById("btn_test").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

edit:I tried to run a function if the **if** statement was true.It's not working just a test.

Comment: What's the [mcve] HTML for this table?

Comment: `if (cell.textContent == 'jhonyy') ...`

Comment: @DavidThomas I already tried to make it minimal this is the simplest code that I cut out from my project.

Comment: Create a snippet with your html code rather than attaching an image.

Comment: @SLePort done thank you.

Comment: Where `cell` is defined?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I'm sorry I copied it on one of the comments.I tried replacing it with `col` still not working.

Comment: The title **does not** ask any question regarding the actual problem you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like that ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table id="tbl_test" style="width:50%">
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jhonyy</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <button id="btn_test" value="test" onclick="test_table()">Test</button>
        <input type="text" id="txt_test" name="txt_test">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test_table()
            {
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl_test");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
               //iterate through rows
               //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
     for (var j = 0, cell; cell = row.cells[j]; j++) {
             //iterate through columns
             //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
      if (cell.textContent == 'Jhonyy') 
      {
       change_text(i);
      }
     }  
    }
            }
            function change_text(row) {
    var txt = document.getElementById("txt_test").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl_test");
    table.rows[row].cells[2].textContent = txt ; // cells[2] => third col
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah.this is defnitly what I want.I wanted to find a tr that matches a string and replace its 3rd column.